# Is there a way in Visual Studio to create a header that automatically includes all headers in a project?

Tags: visual-studio, header, header-files

Is there a way to make Visual Studio automatically maintain a header that includes every other header in the project?

Let's say I have a math library as a project in VS, with the files `sqrt.h`, `round.h`, and `pow.h`. If I want a header that simply includes all the files:

```
#pragma once
#include "sqrt.h"
#include "round.h"
#include "pow.h"
```

Can I somehow in VS create such a header with a click of a button, and if possible have it be maintained automatically? So that if I decide to add a `cos.h` header, VS automatically amends the header and adds a new include statement?